# Page specific preferences firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to build a firefox addon using the latest Addon Builder tool (https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/)

To access global preferences we can make use of simple-prefs api (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-prefs.html)

But **how can we set page specific preferences for our addon?**

*eg. Firebug allows users to disable/enable panel for different pages.*

Comment: Can you be more specific - do you *implement* new page-specific preferences, or ones that the user has already set in some other way? Please provide more info on your use case.

Comment: @canuckistani: clarified question.. I'm trying to implement new page-specific preferences

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're doing, you can look at the [tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/tabs.html) a user has open, and also the active tab to change the behaviour of your add-on for that specific page. Add-ons can exist completely independent of pages and tabs (like a page-worker in the background), or they can affect pages visited (like a page-mod). Depending on your add-on, you can interpret the preferences set and determine what 'page' a user is on from tabs.

Comment: thanks @jsantell, I thought of creating a global object indexed by active tab's id and store all data related to that tab. But what if I load different url/reload the page in that same tab? So the solution would be tab-specific and not page-specific.

Comment: And you'd have access to the active tab and see what URL it's currently set at

Answer (score 0):

To save page specific data, you should use a [file](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/io/file.html) or a database to store it. You can use [simple-storage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/simple-storage.html) or something similar ([indexeddb module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/indexed-db.html)).

Then you add an event listener to the page load, and you check in your database for that page's preferences, and act accordingly.